# How to get docker talking to a server on the same network as the docker host

Tags: docker, networking

I've got a server on my network with a database. I'd like to run a docker container on my Windows machine (using latest Docker CE for Windows so MobyVM) that will run queries against this DB. Starting simple, I'd like to first of all successfully ping the server from inside a docker container.

```
docker run -it ubuntu
```

As ping is needed to test

```
apt-get update && apt-get install iputils-ping
```

Then pinging the server via it's local, non-FQDN, name gets "Destination Host Unreachable".

If I run the docker command with `--network=host` I get the same error.

**What things need to be done to allow a docker container on a windows machine to talk to servers on a network that the host is part of?**

Comment: Instead of ping, try telnet. Is internet working inside the container? Which windows version are you using?

Comment: win10 & latest docker for windows CE

Comment: I checked on my Windows and I am able to ping other machines in my network. May be something to do with your network. See if the network team of yours can help you out

Comment: Thanks Tarun! I suspected "it should just work" but the network docs for docker require far more infrastructure knowledge than I have :)